# conditional substitution using hashes

Tags: perl, hash, substitution

I'm trying for substitution in which a condition will allow or disallow substitution.
I have a string

```
$string = "There is <tag1>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <tag2>you are fool.There <tag3>you got it.";
```

Here are two hashes which are used to check condition.

```
my %tag = ('tag1' => '<you>', 'tag2'=>'<do>', 'tag3'=>'<no>');
my %data = ('you'=>'<you>');
```

Here is actual substitution in which substitution is allowed for hash tag values not matched.

```
$string =~ s{(?<=<(.*?)>)(you)}{
    if($tag{"$1"} eq $data{"$2"}){next;}
    "I"
}sixe;
```

in this code I want to substitute '**you**' with something with the condition that it is not equal to the hash value given in tag. 
Can I use `next` in substitution?
Problem is that **I can't use \g modifier**. And after using `next` I cant go for next substitution.
Also I can't modify expression while matching and using next it dosen't go for second match, it stops there.

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  [`How do I ask a good question?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Miller Question is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple but got my two days to think about it. I just written another substitution where it ignores previous tag which is cancelled by `next;`

```
$string = "There is <tag1>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <tag2>you are fool.There <tag3>you got it.";


my %tag = ('tag1' => '<you>', 'tag2'=>'<do>', 'tag3'=>'<no>');
my %data = ('you'=>'<you>');

my $notag;

$string =~ s{(?<=<(.*?)>)(you)}{
    $notag = $2;
    if($tag{"$1"} eq $data{"$2"}){next;}
    "I"
}sie;

$string =~ s{(?<=<(.*?)>)(?<!$notag)(you)}{
   "I"
}sie;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable length look behind assertion.  The only one that is allowed is the special `\K` marker.

With that in mind, one way to perform this test is the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $string = <DATA>) {
    $string =~ s{<([^>]*)>\K(?!\1)\w+}{I}s;
    print $string;
}

__DATA__
There is <you>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <notyou>you are fool.
There is <you>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <do>you are fool.There <no>you got it.
```

Output:

```
There is <you>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <notyou>I are fool.
There is <you>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <do>I are fool.There <no>you got it.
```

Comment: `$string = "There is <you>you can do for it. that dosen't mean <do>you are fool.There <no>you got it.";` Here only `<do>you` has to be substitute. and it must stop after it. I can't use \g modifier.

Comment: Oh, this is easier then.

Comment: my problem is little complex. here '<.*?>' and 'you' are the hash keys. and condition is that if there value matches substitution go for next match.

Comment: Having a rolling specification is very annoying my friend.  This is why it's much better to specify in detail with examples before writing a question.  This is still potentially easily solved though, unless you change the spec again.

Comment: I have made my final edit.  If you change the spec again, I am only going to engage if you take the time to edit the original question to include a lot of example strings and their expected output.  You can see how my script works with the list of two examples you've thus far provided, so you can't expect us to be able to decipher your intent if you don't give us all the information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51083/discussion-between-wagh-and-miller)